# how to perform a search query of a foreign key field's attribute in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models `Exam` and `Student`.

exam.rb

```
class Exam < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :year
  belongs_to  :student, class_name: "Student"


  def self.search(search)
    if search
      self.where('student. LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      self.all
    end
  end
end
```

student.rb

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to  :year
  has_many  :exams
end
```

The `student` field in `exam.rb` refers to the Student object . However model `Student` has attribute `name` and I want to perform the search based on that attribute and find out the list of exams taken by that student . Is it possible to make such a query ? if so , what would be the correct way to implement it ?

Thanks

Comment: what do you want to find - exams that were taken by some users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it using `joins` and `where`:

```
exams_list = Exams.joins(:student).where('students.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @idej , I used the first options in the `exam.rb` like so `self.joins(:student).where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")` and it did the trick . Thank again

Comment: Sorry, I miss edit with `like` part. Just to note, it's better to specify table name when use join as `where('students.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")` to avoid problems when you have two different tables with some the same named columns and DB don't know which column use for search. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to search text irrespective or case(capitalisation) you can use ilike option for better searching:

```
exams_list = Exams.joins(:student).where('students.name ilike ?', "%#{search}%"))
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    self.joins(:student).where('students.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
  else
    self.all
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.